# Testing router.navigate in Angular to call ngOnInit

Tags: angular, unit-testing

We have an Angular App and as per usual we have services calls in `ngOnInit` of our components. We are writing unit tests and one of the tests we are trying to write is something like:

`if("should get years when navigating to '/'")`

Thing is the ngOnInit does not get called with `router.navigate` I've been reading about and it seems like the instance of the component is still alive and `ngOnInit` have been called before, but if i call `fixture.detectChanges()` it works. So why doesn't it work with `router.navigate`?

Here is our test:

```
  it("should get years only once when navigating to '/'", fakeAsync(() => {
    // Act
    router.navigate([""]);

    tick();

    // Assert
    expect(getAvailableYearsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
```

Here is our component under test:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-component-under-test",
  templateUrl: "./app-component-under-test.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app-component-under-test.scss"]
})
export class ComponentUnderTest implements OnInit {
  public years: Array<number> = [];
  public selectedYear: number;

  constructor(
    private componentUnderTestService: ComponentUnderTestService,
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    let year = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.year) || undefined;

    this.getYears(1, year);
  }

  private getYears(contractId: number, defaultYear?: number): Promise<number> {
    return this.componentUnderTestService.getAvailableYears(contractId).then((years) => {
      this.selectedYear =  defaultYear || years[0];
      this.years = years;

      return this.selectedYear;
    });
  }
}
```

That is our spec:

```
describe("ComponentUnderTest", () => {
  let component: ComponentUnderTest;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentUnderTest>;
  let service: ComponentUnderTestService;

  let getAvailableYearsSpy;

  let router: Router;
  let location: Location;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ComponentUnderTestModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(componentUnderTestRoutes)
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentUnderTest);

    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ComponentUnderTestService);

    getAvailableYearsSpy = spyOn(service, "getAvailableYears").and.returnValue(Promise.resolve([2017, 2018, 2019]));

    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it("should get years and PrognoseMeldung only once when navigating to '/'", fakeAsync(() => {
    // Act
    router.navigate([""]);

    tick();

    // Assert
    expect(getAvailableYearsSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  }));
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including test setup and the component under test.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated my post with the test and component

Comment: As `ComponentUnderTest` has an external template, you're missing a `compileComponents` at the very least - see https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-an-external-template

Comment: as much as I understood compileComponents should be called when you use async which is not my case, nevertheless I added compileComponents and it's still giving that the methods were called 0 times: "spy getAvailableYears to have been called once. It was called 0 times."

Comment: I assume the problem is that I'm using synchronous and it should be async? I'll give it a try

Comment: Were you able to figure out what the problem was, seems like my components init-method isn't called :/